# Using Proxy IP for the users in LAN through Zentyal server

Tags: linux, proxy, server, gateway, zentyal

**Assume:**LAN USERS-->Zentyal Server as Gateway-->Internet.
**Current setup**: All of my LAN users using their subscribed proxy credential in their browser LAN settings to get foreign IP to access my client's website. So the option is in their hand either to use the proxy or to access the site without proxy. My client wants us to access his site using IP from his county. Few times my LAN users accessed his site without proxy.
Requirement: I want all the LAN users to get proxy IP internet through zentyal server to access my client's website in his country. so that the proxy IP from zentyal will be distributed to my LAN users, so they cannot skip using Proxy details.
Please help me to setup the above requirement. Or is there a way to implement the above setup using any other way?